# MySQL DATETIME still depends on timezone

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I have a column in database with type TIMESTAMP.
The problem is when I select records this column has different time than I have in my database (7 hours shift).
I assumed that the problem is in timezone so I changed column type from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME but still when I selecting records server receives it with shifted time.

Should I use different data type?

Comment: This may be driver and/or client issue. Or maybe the value was not shifted during datatype change? in TIMESTAMP it is stored as GMT, and it is possible that it was not recalculated into original timezone (because this info is absent in the data). Try to insert new data using CLI local to the server and compare does it is shifted during retrieve via local CLI and via your client software.

Comment: With `TIMESTAMP`, this is expected behavior. The session time zone applies.  However, with `DATETIME` there should be no shifting going on.  You might want to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html